# Deploying updates to production node.js code

Tags: node.js

This may be a basic question, but how do I go about effeciently deploying updates to currently running node.js code?

I'm coming from a PHP, JavaScript (client-side) background, where I can just overwrite files when they need updating and the changes are instantly available on the produciton site.

But in node.js I have to overwrite the existing files, then shut-down and the re-launch the application. Should I be worried by potential downtime in this? To me it seems like a more risky approach than the PHP (scripting) way. Unless I have a server cluster, where I can take down one server at a time for updates.

What kind of strategies are available for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case it's pretty much:

`svn up; monit restart node`

This Node server is acting as a comet server with long polling clients, so clients just reconnect like they normally would.  The first thing the Node server does is grab the current state info from the database, so everything is running smoothly in no time.

I don't think this is really any riskier than doing an `svn up` to update a bunch of PHP files.  If anything it's a little bit safer.  When you're updating a big php project, there's a chance (if it's a high traffic site it's basically a 100% chance) that you could be getting requests over the web server while you're still updating.  This means that you would be running updated and out-of-date code in the same request.  At least with the Node approach, you can update *everything* and restart the Node server and know that all your code is up to date.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't worry too much about downtime, you should be able to keep this so short that chances are no one will notice (kill the process and re-launch it in a bash script or something if you want to keep it to a fraction of a second).

Of more concern however is that many Node applications keep a lot of state information in memory which you're going to lose when you restart it. For example if you were running a chat application it might not remember who users were talking to or what channels/rooms they were in. Dealing with this is more of a design issue though, and very application specific.

Comment: Yup. This is the reason why it makes sense to store for instance session data in persistent database rather than memory.

Answer (score 2):

If your node.js application 'can't skip a beat' meaning it is under continuous bombardment of incoming requests, you just simply cant afford that downtime of a quick restart (even with nodemon). I think in some cases you simply want a seamless restart of your node.js apps.
To do this I use naught: https://github.com/superjoe30/naught
Zero downtime deployment for your Node.js server using builtin cluster API

Answer (score 1):

Some of the cloud hosting providers Node.js (like NodeJitsu or Windows Azure) keep both versions of your site on disk on separate directories and just redirect the traffic from one version to the new version once the new version has been fully deployed.

This is usually a built-in feature of Platform as a Service (PaaS) providers. However, if you are managing your servers you'll need to build something to allow for traffic to go from one version to the next once the new one has been fully deployed.

An advantage of this approach is that then rollbacks are easy since the previous version remains on the site intact.